# I am creating a program to convert number of total years to decades and years. One of my outputs is being a little weird

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ElapsedTime_struct {
   int decadesVal;
   int yearsVal;
} ElapsedTime;

ElapsedTime ConvertToDecadesAndYears(int totalYears) {
   ElapsedTime tempVal;

   tempVal.decadesVal = totalYears/10;
   tempVal.yearsVal = (((double) totalYears/10) - tempVal.decadesVal) * 10;

   return tempVal;

}

int main(void) {
   ElapsedTime elapsedYears;
   int totalYears;

   scanf("%d", &totalYears);

   elapsedYears = ConvertToDecadesAndYears(totalYears);

   printf("%d decades and %d years\n", elapsedYears.decadesVal, elapsedYears.yearsVal);

   return 0;
}
```

my logic is that if you take number of total years( 26) and divide the integer value by 10, you will get the number of decades. int (26/10) = 2

my logic for the number of years is that if you take the double value of 26/10, you will get 2.6000

then subtracting 2.6 - 2 (number of decades), you will get the decimal value for the number of years(0.6)

i then multiplied by 10 to get a whole value (6) so together its 2 decades and 6 years.

**however when i try running the code for some inputs (34 total years) i am getting 3 decades and 3 years for some reason whereas i should get 3 decades and 4 years.**

i am confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: `totalYears % 10` is the leftover years, `totalYears / 10` is the number of decades. Don't use floating point to solve integer problems or you risk running into issues like you've seen.

Comment: You should be using the remainder operator %, so year = totalYears % 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point math is inexact.  Values such as 2.6 and 3.3 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point.  You instead end up with a value that is either slightly larger or slightly smaller.

The latter case is what you're seeing.  3.4 is stored as roughly 3.39999999999999991.  Subtracting 3 from that and multiplying by 10 gives you 3.9999999999999991, then when you convert that to an `int` the fractional part is truncated giving you 3.

That being said, you don't need floating point operations here.  You can instead use the modulus operator `%` to get the remainder when dividing by 10.

```
tempVal.yearsVal = totalYears%10;
```